.NET Socket Listen backlog not working as expected
I am testing a simple TCP server in C# that I aim to be able to connect 10k clients concurrently:
Server
public class HighPerfTcpServer
{
    private Socket? _listeningSocket;

    private ILogger<HighPerfTcpServer> _logger;

    public HighPerfTcpServer(ILogger<HighPerfTcpServer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<int> Start(TcpServerOptions options, ITcpServerSessionsHandler sessionHandler)
    {
        var address = options.Address ?? "127.0.0.1";
        var port = options.Port ?? 0;
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(address);
        var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        _listeningSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        _listeningSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        _listeningSocket.Listen(int.MaxValue);

        var acceptArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        acceptArgs.Completed += AcceptArgs_Completed;

        StartAccept(acceptArgs);

        var currentLocalEndPoint = _listeningSocket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(currentLocalEndPoint);

        return currentLocalEndPoint.Port;
    }

    private void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptArgs)
    {
        if (_listeningSocket == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var willRaiseEvent = false;

        while (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            acceptArgs.AcceptSocket = null;

            try
            {
                willRaiseEvent = _listeningSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptArgs);

                if (!willRaiseEvent)
                {
                    ProcessAccept(acceptArgs);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }

            
        }
    }

    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptArgs)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"client connected");
    }

    private void AcceptArgs_Completed(object? sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Accept)
        {
            ProcessAccept(e);

            StartAccept(e);
        }
    }

    public async Task Stop()
    {
        _listeningSocket?.Dispose();
    }
}

Client
public class HighPerfTcpClient
{
    private TaskCompletionSource? _connectAwaiter;
    private TaskCompletionSource? _disconnectAwaiter;
    private Socket? _clientSocket;

    public async Task<ITcpClientConnection> Connect(TcpClientOptions options)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options.Address);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options.Port);

        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(options.Address);
        var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, options.Port.Value);

        _clientSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        var connectEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        connectEventArgs.Completed += ConnectEventArgs_Completed;
        connectEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;

        _connectAwaiter = new TaskCompletionSource();

        var willRaiseEvent = _clientSocket.ConnectAsync(connectEventArgs);

        if (willRaiseEvent)
        {
            await _connectAwaiter.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        if (connectEventArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception($"socket connect error: {connectEventArgs.SocketError}");
        }

        return new TcpClientConnection(DataSender);
    }

    private async Task DataSender(ArraySegment<byte> segment)
    {
    
    }

    private void ConnectEventArgs_Completed(object? sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Connect)
        {
            _connectAwaiter?.SetResult();
        }
    }

    public async Task Disconnect()
    {
        if (_clientSocket != null)
        {
            var disconnectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

            disconnectArgs.Completed += DisconnectArgs_Completed;

            _disconnectAwaiter = new TaskCompletionSource();

            var willRaiseEvent = _clientSocket.DisconnectAsync(disconnectArgs);

            if (willRaiseEvent)
            {
                await _disconnectAwaiter.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DisconnectArgs_Completed(object? sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Disconnect)
        {
            _disconnectAwaiter?.SetResult();
        }
    }
}

Test Case
public class TcpClientServerIntegrationTests
{
    private static ILoggerFactory _factory;

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_be_able_to_up_server_and_clients_connect_and_disconnect()
    {
        var testLogger = GetLogger<TcpClientServerIntegrationTests>();

        var sessionHandlerMock = new Mock<ITcpServerSessionsHandler>();
        var server = new HighPerfTcpServer(GetLogger<HighPerfTcpServer>());

        var connections = 10 * 1000;

        var port = 10000;

        var tcpServerOptions = new TcpServerOptions
        {
            Address = "127.0.0.1",
            ConnectionBufferSize = 128 * 1024,
            MaxConnections = connections,
            Port = port
        };

        var startedPort = await server.Start(tcpServerOptions, sessionHandlerMock.Object);

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, connections).Select(e =>
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var client = new HighPerfTcpClient();
                var clientOptions = new TcpClientOptions
                {
                    Address = "127.0.0.1",
                    Port = startedPort,
                    BufferSize = 128 * 1024,
                    OnData = OnClientData,
                    OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect
                };

                await client.Connect(clientOptions);

                testLogger.LogDebug($"{e} client connected");

                await client.Disconnect();

                testLogger.LogDebug($"{e} client disconnected");
            });
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task OnDisconnect()
    {

    }

    private async Task OnClientData(ArraySegment<byte> segment)
    {

    }

    private ILogger<T> GetLogger<T>()
    {
        return _factory.CreateLogger<T>();
    }

    static TcpClientServerIntegrationTests()
    {
        var configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var target = new FileTarget();

        target.FileName = "./logs/log.${logger}.txt";
        target.KeepFileOpen = false;

        configuration.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, NLog.LogLevel.Error, target);

        _factory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddNLog(configuration);
        });
    }
}

When the test is run, the server only gets a connection for about 2k connections and the rest of clients are thrown with error ConnectionRefused, where I would expect all 10k requests are completed since the Listen method of server is given a backlog of int.MaxValue.
I tried to use different possible values for the backlog and found no difference. Anyone can shed some light on this issue?

You're probably running out of sockets. Normally you wouldn't have so many sockets open at once, you would handle requests and close them once done, so only a few are open at any given time. Note that rolling your own TCP protocol is fraught with difficulties and should be avoided if at all possible, see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html

To determine the maximum number of connections you can specify, retrieve the MaxConnections value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.listen?view=net-8.0#system-net-sockets-socket-listen(system-int32)

@Charlieface, I can open 10k connections fine if I do it in a for loop than doing concurrently. So it means, it is not an issue with running out of sockets.

@shingo, it is int.MaxValue in .net core 8.0

The code isn't doing anything with the sockets (not actually reading them) so it's possible it's jst running ot of buffer space. You need to hand off the newly received socket to another thread or task, and continue listening, not just dump the socket. Also willRaiseEvent = _listeningSocket.AcceptAsync feels wrong to me, not sure what it's trying to achieve as the bool only tells you whether it completed asynchronously or synchronously. Honestly not sure why you aren't using async Task everywhere here, and why not use TcpListener which does most of the work for you.

@Charlieface, this is just a test setup. Please check the documentation of SocketAsyncEventArgs how the AcceptAsync works. I don't want to use TcpListner since it is not high performing.

On that page, it also says "The backlog parameter is limited to different values depending on the Operating System. You may specify a higher value, but the backlog will be limited based on the Operating System.", and on this Winsock2 page: "There is no standard provision to find out the actual backlog value". So you can assume that the backlog has a maximum value and is limited by the OS.

Well how do you expect us to diagnose a problem if you aren't showing representative code? Also this whole design is rather strange, why aren't you using the proper Task Async functions, which are much more efficient, if you are so worried about performance?

@Charlieface why do you think .NET provides the socketasynceventargs construct in that case?

Because they have been there since .NET 2, well before the advent of async and Task based processing. And I'm not sure why you claim TcpListener has major perf issues more than raw sockets, I'm not aware of any so please link because I'd love to know. Either way, without more info we can't help.
